# Heroku runs fine local but not online

Tags: node.js, git, express, heroku, mongoose-web-server

So looking at my logs, I see this:

```
2016-10-24T05:42:16.071986+00:00 app[web.1]: var app = express();
2016-10-24T05:42:16.071987+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2016-10-24T05:42:16.071987+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-24T05:42:16.071988+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: express is not a function
2016-10-24T05:42:16.071989+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:2:11)
2016-10-24T05:42:16.071989+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
2016-10-24T05:42:16.071990+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
2016-10-24T05:42:16.071990+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
2016-10-24T05:42:16.071990+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
2016-10-24T05:42:16.071991+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
2016-10-24T05:42:16.071991+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (node.js:148:18)
2016-10-24T05:42:16.071995+00:00 app[web.1]:     at node.js:405:3
2016-10-24T05:42:16.162284+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-24T05:42:25.379955+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/local" host=murmuring-reef-69157.herokuapp.com request_id=3c2c9cc9-d1b2-48b1-b628-bd5d8030fd0e fwd="98.210.167.212" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-24T05:42:26.006599+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=murmuring-reef-69157.herokuapp.com request_id=f4507e17-8202-46cf-ad81-4737ccd1bbab fwd="98.210.167.212" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-24T05:48:10.261072+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=murmuring-reef-69157.herokuapp.com request_id=f3d0a1b2-4d0c-4ad7-af35-d18e0b3e6e72 fwd="98.210.167.212" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-24T05:48:10.866238+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=murmuring-reef-69157.herokuapp.com request_id=12526a0f-14c2-4ecf-88c7-a656000c9d6d fwd="98.210.167.212" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-24T05:49:48.551924+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-10-24T05:49:51.371049+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2016-10-24T05:49:53.339799+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app.js:2
2016-10-24T05:49:53.339818+00:00 app[web.1]: var app = express();
2016-10-24T05:49:53.339819+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2016-10-24T05:49:53.339819+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-24T05:49:53.339821+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:2:11)
2016-10-24T05:49:53.339822+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
2016-10-24T05:49:53.339820+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: express is not a function
2016-10-24T05:49:53.339823+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
2016-10-24T05:49:53.339823+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
2016-10-24T05:49:53.339824+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
2016-10-24T05:49:53.339824+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
2016-10-24T05:49:53.339825+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (node.js:148:18)
2016-10-24T05:49:53.339825+00:00 app[web.1]:     at node.js:405:3
2016-10-24T05:49:53.462911+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-10-24T05:49:53.481857+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-24T05:51:59.092552+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=murmuring-reef-69157.herokuapp.com request_id=83f531a2-2855-4c25-bd31-21293e939156 fwd="98.210.167.212" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-24T05:51:59.702922+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=murmuring-reef-69157.herokuapp.com request_id=a4d24924-75a4-4440-8f14-a914ea1441f4 fwd="98.210.167.212" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-24T05:55:27.129395+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 383a228 by kenzom954@gmail.com
2016-10-24T05:55:27.129485+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v9 created by kenzom954@gmail.com
2016-10-24T05:55:27.308319+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-10-24T05:55:27.308324+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-10-24T05:55:27.289407+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-10-24T05:55:30.183810+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2016-10-24T05:55:32.094514+00:00 app[web.1]: var app = express();
2016-10-24T05:55:32.094515+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2016-10-24T05:55:32.094499+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app.js:2
2016-10-24T05:55:32.094516+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: express is not a function
2016-10-24T05:55:32.094516+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-24T05:55:32.094517+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:2:11)
2016-10-24T05:55:32.094518+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
2016-10-24T05:55:32.094519+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
2016-10-24T05:55:32.094520+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
2016-10-24T05:55:32.094521+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
2016-10-24T05:55:32.094520+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
2016-10-24T05:55:32.094522+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (node.js:148:18)
2016-10-24T05:55:32.094522+00:00 app[web.1]:     at node.js:405:3
2016-10-24T05:55:32.206636+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-24T05:55:32.190134+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-10-24T05:58:55.619526+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 211f725 by kenzom954@gmail.com
2016-10-24T05:58:55.619564+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v10 created by kenzom954@gmail.com
2016-10-24T05:58:55.819150+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-10-24T05:58:55.819157+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-10-24T05:58:56.098775+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-10-24T05:58:59.294388+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2016-10-24T05:59:01.290759+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:341
2016-10-24T05:59:01.290772+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2016-10-24T05:59:01.290773+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2016-10-24T05:59:01.290774+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-24T05:59:01.290775+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'body-parser'
2016-10-24T05:59:01.290776+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
2016-10-24T05:59:01.290776+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
2016-10-24T05:59:01.290777+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
2016-10-24T05:59:01.290778+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2016-10-24T05:59:01.290778+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:3:18)
2016-10-24T05:59:01.290779+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
2016-10-24T05:59:01.290780+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
2016-10-24T05:59:01.290780+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
2016-10-24T05:59:01.290781+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
2016-10-24T05:59:01.290781+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
2016-10-24T05:59:01.369506+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-24T05:59:01.356300+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-10-24T05:59:03.922494+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=murmuring-reef-69157.herokuapp.com request_id=167632f8-7e55-4961-9a96-c630a5bfd05c fwd="98.210.167.212" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-24T05:59:04.559487+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=murmuring-reef-69157.herokuapp.com request_id=2facb77e-53f1-4f95-b150-7f7e05b9622e fwd="98.210.167.212" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-24T06:01:06.014637+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-10-24T06:01:09.793263+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2016-10-24T06:01:11.927280+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:341
2016-10-24T06:01:11.927293+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2016-10-24T06:01:11.927294+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-24T06:01:11.927294+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2016-10-24T06:01:11.927295+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'body-parser'
2016-10-24T06:01:11.927296+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
2016-10-24T06:01:11.927296+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
2016-10-24T06:01:11.927297+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
2016-10-24T06:01:11.927297+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2016-10-24T06:01:11.927298+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:3:18)
2016-10-24T06:01:11.927299+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
2016-10-24T06:01:11.927299+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
2016-10-24T06:01:11.927300+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
2016-10-24T06:01:11.927300+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
2016-10-24T06:01:11.927301+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
2016-10-24T06:01:12.028090+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-10-24T06:01:12.045170+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

However, I made sure to `npm install` my **package.json** before pushing to `git push heroku master`.

When I run locally by `heroku local` it works fine, but `heroku open` leads me to those erros.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var port = process.env.PORT ||  3000;
var crypto = require("crypto");
var path = require('path');
var config = require('./config'); // holds information about hosting
var Url = require('./models/Url.model'); //this holds our Schema model
var LookUp = require('./models/Lookup.model.js'); //this holds our Schema lookup
var db ='mongodb://heroku_0xrn515v:v09cpj5t25qtm73klv2poj5n5h@ds031157.mlab.com:31157/heroku_0xrn515v'

mongoose.connect(db)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views/index.html'));
})

app.post('/api/shorten',function(req,res){
  var regex = /https:\/\/|http:\/\//
    //Check if the user input correctly with http or https format
    //if true, proceed. Otherwise, return a string with home direct link
  if(regex.test(req.body.long_url)){
    var longUrl = req.body.long_url;
    var shortUrl = ""
    //check if document (url) exist already in collection
    Url.findOne({
      long_url : longUrl
    })
      .exec(function(err,result){
        if (err) throw err
        else{
          //if the long url is in the collection, simply return the short_url
          if(result){
            LookUp.findOne({
              key: result._id
            })
              .exec(function(err,result){
                res.send({shortUrl: config.webhost + result.shortUrl,
                  shortUrlString: config.webhost + result.shortUrl })
              })
          }
          //if the long url isn't in the collection, make a new short_url for it
          else{
            var newUrl = new Url();
            newUrl.long_url = longUrl
            newUrl.save( function(err,result){
              if(err){
                console.log('error!')
              } else{
                var newLookUp = new LookUp();
                newLookUp.key = result._id;
                var id = crypto.randomBytes(2).toString('hex');
                newLookUp.shortUrl = id
                newLookUp.save( function( err, result){
                  if (err) throw err
                  else{
                    res.send({shortUrl: config.webhost + result.shortUrl,
                    shortUrlString: config.webhost + result.shortUrl})
                  }
                })
              }
            })
          }
        }
      })
  } else{
    res.send({shortUrl: "#"
      ,shortUrlString: 'Remember to put in https:// format!'})
  }
})

app.get('/:id', function(req, res){
  var shortenURL = req.params.id;
  LookUp.findOne({
    shortUrl: shortenURL
  })
    .exec(function(err,result){
      Url.findOne({
        _id: result.key
      })
        .exec(function(err,resultLink){
          res.redirect(resultLink.long_url)
        })
    })
});

app.listen(port,function(){
  console.log('listening in port', port)
})
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "shortenerurl",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "crypto": "0.0.3",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.6.5"
  }
}
```

**Procfile**

```
web: node app.js
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be a problem with the Node version that Heroku is using. You could try [setting Heroku to use the same one you use locally](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#specify-the-version-of-node). Also, you don't need to do an `npm install` before deploying to Heroku, as it will to it for you when you deploy (so don't include the node_module folder on git).

Comment: I noticed that in my `.gitignore`, I included node_modules. Perhaps, I need to exclude that from it?

Comment: (you want the node modules to be installed on the environment they will run)

Comment: Yep, it looked like that's all I had to fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was in the environment variables. In my local system, I had .env file for `Environment variables` but I forgot to set the Environment variable on heroku, that was giving me error. You can set the ENV variable with

```
$ heroku config:set ENV_KEY="the_value"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this bug and after lot of searching here and there @hammad 's answer worked for me and how you can set config vars by two ways

1. using heroku CLI.
2. using dashboard (very easy which i followed).
   dashboard > your app > settings > config vars > set key = value
   that's it.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars